Algorithm for Compact Representation of Tuples Using Cartesian Product
I have the following set of tuples:
('red', 'hot', 'big'),
('red', 'hot', 'small'),
('red', 'cold', 'big'),
('blue', 'hot', 'big'),
('blue', 'cold', 'big'),
('green', 'hot', 'big'),
('green', 'cold', 'big')

I would like to create a compact representation of the above, where a tuple element can be a list of allowed values. The intention is that given a representation like this, one can easily generate the original set by applying the Cartesian product. The result of the transformation might look like this:
('red', ['hot', 'cold'], 'big'),
('red', 'hot', 'small'),
(['blue', 'green'], ['hot', 'cold'], 'big')

I want the representation to be as compact as possible. Can you suggest an algorithm, preferably a well-known one?
Edit
This is just an example. I'm looking for a general solution where the tuple can be of any length, and the number of alternatives at each position is not limited to 2.

[(['blue', 'green', 'red'], ['cold', 'hot'], 'big'),  ('red', 'hot', 'small')] With two alternatives per "dimension", this is what [boolean]logic optimization is about.

I've edited the question to clarify that the number of alternatives is not limited to 2

Do not let that keep you from looking at logic minimisation approaches for ideas.

Algorithm for Compact Tuple Representation
Group tuples by similarity:
Partition the tuples by their values in each position. Identify where specific positions vary while others remain fixed.
Generalize variable positions:
For each group of tuples that differ in a single position, replace the varying elements in that position with a list of the allowed values.
Merge groups:
Attempt to merge groups where possible by comparing the lists and combining them if they differ in only one position.
Iterate until compact:
Repeat the above steps until no further merging or generalization is possible.

Is there a specific order or logic behind how the tuples are grouped? Considering there could be numerous ways to organize them, I'd like to understand the reasoning.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

From a graph theory aspect, each attribute can be a vertex ("blue", "big", .etc), and each tuple is an edge in the 3-uniform 3-partite hypergraph. The problem then boils down to finding the minimum triclique cover. However, even finding the minimum clique cover of an ordinary graph is NP-hard, so I doubt you'll find a polynomial-time solution for this variant.
I expect that a greedy approach that finds large tricliques and repeatedly removes them (inserting the corresponding Cartesian product tuple into the solution set) is probably your best bet.

Can you elaborate on " a greedy approach that finds large tricliques and repeatedly removes them"?
